# Which keywords are reserved in JavaScript but not in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, grammar

Which keywords are reserved in JavaScript but not in Java?

One example is `debugger`, but there are more.

By *reserved* I mean *reserved words* as well as *future reserved words* (in both strict and non-strict mode) and special tokens like `null`, `true` and `false`.

I'm interested in ECMAScript 5.1 as well as current 6 vs. Java 5-8 (not sure if there were new keywords since Java 5).

**Update**

For those who's interested in reasons to know this.

- I know many Java developers switching from Java to JavaScript (my story). Knowing delta in keywords is helpful.
- Language history.
- My very specific reason for asking: I'm building code Java/JavaScript code generation tools (quasi cross-langiuage). Which reserved keywords should I add to Java code generator so that it produces JavaScript-compatible identifiers in cross-language case?

Comment: ... ?? Can't you just get the lists from the respective specs and compare them?

Comment: @Pointy This is Q&A for future reference.

Comment: Oh OK. Carry on then :)

Comment: Since both languages have specifications that provide well-defined sets of reserved words (the ES5 specification covers 'strict' as well) it is as simple as `{reserved_js} - {reserved_java}`, trivial to do with many programs (I'd use LINQPad) once the sets are loaded. As such, I'm not really sure where this question is going.

Comment: What would be the purpose of knowing this? You could next be asking "Which keywords are reserved in Python but not in C#?". I see no value whatsoever in having these type of questions on so, sorry.

Comment: I have downvoted this because I don't feel that Stack Overflow should become the reference site for this kind of information.  Both Java and Javascript have normative reference sites.  This just feels completely superfluous to me, as well as likely to become out of date.

Comment: JavaScript originally was created with all the same reserved words as Java, but their syntax and reserved words grew more different over time. This is related to this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#JavaScript_and_Java

Comment: I'm torn on whether to close this as off topic. Though it has to do with programming languages, it doesn't seem to be about _programming_ at in any practical sense (and the on-topic page does suggest questions should be practical).

Comment: @BartKiers Please see the update of the question.

Comment: Re your update, I don't get how the delta of keywords is useful to a code generation tool (and ditto to a human learning one language or the other, except as a kind of trivia). The syntaxes are different enough that I would think each side of the code generation should just do its own thing, not caring about what the other side's keywords are (or its other syntax features).

Comment: @yshavit I generate JavaScript code in [JAXB RI](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb) plugin which is actually for Java. I'm using the same property names in my generated JavaScript code. JAXB RI only consideres [Java reserved names](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/2c38ef0af8be867dc6b1b039eed9dfb3f9321c4d/jaxb-ri/codemodel/codemodel/src/main/java/com/sun/codemodel/JJavaName.java#L146-L204). To produce syntactically correct JavaScript I have to extend this list with JavaScript reserved words. This is why I need the delta.

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm may be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I've found out so far.

There were seems to be no new keywords in Java since 5.0 (which added `enum`).

Java vs. ECMAScript 5.1:

- `debugger`
- `delete`
- `function`
- `in`
- `typeof`
- `var`
- `with`
- `export`
- `let`
- `yield`

Java vs. ECMAScript 6 Rev 36 Release Candidate 3:

- all of above
- `await`

Comment: @DavidWallace `eval`?

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp - and yes, I know that W3Schools is kind of an unreliable source.  I've certainly used eval though.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, not according to [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1). So the question might not be so superfluous as it may seem.

Comment: The `eval` symbol is "special" but it's not a *reserved* word. You can redifine it if you like, just like `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, the W3Schools page has shot its credibility in the foot by also listing `eval` and `function` among its "built-in objects, properties and methods".  While those are obviously not the same things as "reserved words", if you're writing something that converts Java to JS, you'll want to "fix up" any cases where words like `eval` and `undefined` have been used as identifier names.

Comment: @DavidWallace My only goal is to produce syntactically correct JavaScript. I'd better leave things like redefining `eval` to the *SLint.

Comment: _Your_ only goal (@lexicore) may differ from the goals of other people who want to use this question, if they exist.  Of course, if the goals of others are not being considered here, then that lends weight to my belief that this question has no business being on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you for the feedback. I'm fully OK with downvotes and closing, this is why what we have community for. I honestly believed this is a useful and not a trivial question. I see this opinion is not widely shared :) but that's OK.

Comment: @yshavit I'm simply prepending names matching reserved names with `_`. `eval` and likes do not pose a problem for the code I generate. Reserved words do.